# OrderBy compiling but not ordering

Tags: c#

I am trying to order a list for a league table with the following code:

```
leagueTeamRow.OrderBy(c => c.points).ThenBy(c => c.goalDifference);
```

The code compiles, but the items are not being sorted, they still display in the default order.

This is my class

```
public class LeagueRow
    {
        public String teamName { get; set; }
        public String managerName { get; set; }
        public Int32 played { get; set; }
        public Int32 won { get; set; }
        public Int32 draw { get; set; }
        public Int32 lost { get; set; }
        public Int32 goalsFor { get; set; }
        public Int32 goalsAgainst { get; set; }
        public Int32 goalDifference { get; set; }
        public Int32 points { get; set; }
    }
```

Can anyone suggest what I am missing?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < leagueTeamRow.Count; i++){
LeagueTable.Text += "<tr><td>" + positionCount + "</td><td>" + leagueTeamRow[i].teamName..
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the result of the ordering to a variable or something:

```
var ordered = leagueTeamRow.OrderBy(c => c.points).ThenBy(c => c.goalDifference);
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to output this data, previosuly I was using

for (int i = 0; i < leagueTeamRow.Count; i++)

how can I do this with the varaible ordered?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but I think wht your looking for is `foreach (var row in ordered) { // do stuff }`

Comment: Amazing, thanks ! How do I switch the order in reverse? Its putting them ascending, I want it descending

Comment: use `.OrderByDescending` instead of `.OrderBy`

Answer (score 4):

You are missing that `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` don't order the list in place, they return a new, ordered list.

This is the same pattern used by all LINQ methods.

Answer (score 3):

Are you referencing `leagueTeamRow` when you're checking the ordering? You need to save the result of `OrderBy` to a variable.

So

```
var orderedLeagueTeamRow = leagueTeamRow.OrderBy(c => c.points).ThenBy(c => c.goalDifference);
```

Answer (score 3):

OrderBy returns an `IOrderedEnumerable`: a list or something that implements IEnumerable, and then are ordered. You're not assigning that !

```
var ordered = leagueTeamRow.OrderBy(c => c.points).ThenBy(c => c.goalDifference);
```

In ordered variable, are ordered as you set

See more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to output this data, previosuly I was using

for (int i = 0; i < leagueTeamRow.Count; i++)

how can I do this with the varaible ordered?

Comment: as you can see in the link, you can use foreach clause in the ordered lsit

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to assign the result of you statement to a variable

```
var ordered = leagueTeamRow.OrderBy(c => c.points).ThenBy(c => c.goalDifference);
```